# Initializing a JComboBox object using a String array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I did it as follows, but it wouldn't work:

```
JComboBox brand = new JComboBox({"Pizza Hut", "Papa John's", "Dominos" });
```

The error is:
`Syntax error on token "new", @ expected after this token`

Kindly help me understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't short cut the creation of the array, you need to provide more information so the compiler can resolve the types, for example

```
JComboBox brand = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Pizza Hut", "Papa John's", "Dominos" });
```

Comment: Can I use new String[] instead of new Object[]?

Comment: @GuptillGunther Yes, but unless you use generics like `JComboBox<String> brand = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Pizza Hut", "Papa John's", "Dominos"});` it will have little meaning to the `JComboBox`